# Convert matrix into dataframe using content in the cell

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I am trying to convert a NxM matrix into a dataframe:
for example, 2x2 matrix with row as A,B and column as 1,2, such as:

[image]

The cells inside each matrix contains 12 strings. I want to convert this matrix into 12 columns (same length as the strings), so it will look something like this, except with 12 columns

[image]

I tried using code below but no luck. Any help is appreciated!

```
       sample_layout = pd.read_excel(file_name.xlxs,engine='openpyxl',sheet_name=1, skiprows=0) #skip the first row which is the indexes of the well
              
       column_names = ['ID','sample_ID','sample_type','pilot_batch','tissue','hide_ID','hide_replicate','avg loaded weight mg','avg empty weight mg','net weight mg','date','operator']
                    
       df_converted = pd.DataFrame(sample_layout, columns=column_names)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the data is like in your example, you can do this:

```
import pandas as pd

df.melt()['value'].str.split(',', expand=True)

# similar alternative:
df.stack().str.split(',', expand=True)

# Output
   0             1        2    3  4        5  6         7         8        9      10  11
0  19  SZ-0602-3- 1   sample  602  3  0602- 3  1  1640.605    1629.3  11.305   45133  SZ
1  20  SZ-0602-3- 2   sample  602  3  0602- 3  2  1628.315  1617.095   11.2 2  45133  SZ
2  19  SZ-0602-3- 1   sample  602  3  0602- 3  1  1640.605    1629.3  11.305   45133  SZ
3  20  SZ-0602-3- 2   sample  602  3  0602- 3  2  1628.315  1617.095   11.2 2  45133  SZ

# Reproducible data:
df = pd.DataFrame({
    1: ["19,SZ-0602-3- 1, sample,602,3,0602- 3,1,1640.605,1629.3,11.305 ,45133,SZ", "20,SZ-0602-3- 2, sample,602,3,0602- 3,2,1628.315,1617.095,11.2 2,45133,SZ"],
    2: ["19,SZ-0602-3- 1, sample,602,3,0602- 3,1,1640.605,1629.3,11.305 ,45133,SZ", "20,SZ-0602-3- 2, sample,602,3,0602- 3,2,1628.315,1617.095,11.2 2,45133,SZ"]
})
```

Comment: beautiful. thank you so much Mark! Just curious - if i want to have my output to arrange in order by 19,19, 20, 20 (column 0). Can i do stack() instead of melt()?

Comment: you can! see update @wew044